# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT ' to data type tinyint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get value of a column of a particular row but I am getting following error. I don't know what's the problem. Here is my sql query:

```
declare @Service_Table varchar(30),
        @Ser_Id tinyint,
        @sql  nvarchar(100), 
        @Service_State tinyint

SET @Service_Table='Third_Party_Assistance'
set @Ser_Id = 2
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @Service_State + '=  Service_State_Id FROM dbo.' + 
          quotename(@Service_Table) + ' WHERE Service_Id = ' + 
          convert(varchar,@Ser_Id) + 'AND Service_State_Id <> 4'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, CHANGED IT BUT STILL PROBLEM.

Comment: It looks like you have a closing bracket but not an opening one, are you missing a bracket near SELECT -> (SELECT ? unless you need to add one before the case for @Ser_ID ?

Comment: @christiandev, but it is not a problem. I have tried by removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) system stored procedure with OUTPUT parameter

```
declare @Service_Table varchar(30),
        @Ser_Id tinyint,
        @sql  nvarchar(4000), 
        @Service_State tinyint

SET @Service_Table='Third_Party_Assistance'
SET @Ser_Id = 2
SET @sql = 'SELECT @Service_State =  Service_State_Id FROM dbo.' + 
            quotename(@Service_Table) + ' WHERE Service_Id = ' +
            '@Ser_Id AND Service_State_Id <> 4'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Ser_Id tinyint, @Service_State tinyint OUTPUT', @Ser_Id, @Service_State OUTPUT
SELECT @Service_State
```

Comment: I am not able to print @Service_State Value.

Answer (score 1):

You did not assign any value to @Service_State variable !!

Comment: I am assigning it using select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you already ask this question?
Where are the declarations?

Try casting @Service_State: `cast(@Service_State) as varchar(255))`

```
declare @Service_Table varchar(30),
        @Ser_Id tinyint,
        @sql  nvarchar(30), 
        @Service_State tinyint

SET @Service_Table='Third_Party_Assistance'
set @Ser_Id = 2
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + cast(@Service_State as varchar(255))+ '=  Service_State_Id FROM dbo.' + 
          quotename(@Service_Table) + ' WHERE Service_Id = ' + 
          convert(varchar,@Ser_Id) + 'AND Service_State_Id <> 4)'
```

Comment: Well it executed but I am not able to getting any value. when I try to print @Service_State, It is not printing anything.

Comment: Try:
 

       SET @sql = '(SELECT Service_State_Id FROM dbo.' + 
                  quotename(@Service_Table) + ' WHERE Service_Id = ' + 
                  convert(varchar,@Ser_Id) + 'AND Service_State_Id <> 4)'

Comment: Your query is working but I need to assign Service_State into variable so I can check it in if condition. and it is giving me error if I use Service_State_Id<>4. The error is: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Service_State_I'.